# Chrome Timeline buffer usage

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, optimization, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to optimize the animations of а sitе.

I'm using Chrome dev tools(network/timeline/profile) to get some stats and have found out that when I track the timeline, the usage always buffers to 100% in very short time.

I make a test on stackoverflow and the buffer usage doesn't behave in the same way.

> My questions are:
>
> - What exactly is "buffer usage"?
> - Should I be worried about it, and if "yes" - how to improve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

p.s. sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turning on the timeline logs events into the buffer. When the buffer is full, Chrome will try to log selectively, but you'll lose a lot of events. The rate at which the buffer fills depends on how much happens on the page. I'm guessing that your page has a lot of elements while StackOverflow has a pretty simple page and that's the reason behind the different buffer fill rates.

You can see more from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log)